# Finding the limit as $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I know the answer is supposed to be 2 but I do not understand.
$${\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}} \frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2} +1}-1}$$
I tried using intuition by reasoning that the numerator will be virtually $0$, and as the value under the root will be slightly greater than $1$, the root of a value slightly greater than $1$ will also be slightly greater than one. Then by subtracting $1$ that means the answer will be $0$.

Please explain where the flaw in my intuition is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you may let $z=x^2+y^2$.  Then, we are asked to find the limit

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}-1}&=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{z}{\sqrt{z+1}-1}\\\\
&=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{z(\sqrt{z+1}+1)}{z}\\\\
&=2
\end{align}$$

Comment: I had the same idea. You can arrive at this too by letting $x=r \cos(\theta)$ and $y=r \sin(\theta)$. Then it's simply a problem of finding a limit as $r \to 0$.

Comment: @Harry Polar coordinates works, but is not the way to go here.

Comment: It should be added that my approach does need l'hôpital's rule also to arrive at the correct answer.

Comment: @Harry Certainly your approach is valid.  And why are you discussing LHR?  It was not used in the solution herein.

Comment: Because this is a multivariable limit, it may (?) be safe to assume that derivatives of single variable functions have been covered. In which case we have the option to realize that your second limit is the reciprocal of the derivative of $\sqrt x$ at $x=1$. Nothing wrong with this, of course. I felt like pointing out this (and the change to single variable), and a natural place is a comment under you answer.

Comment: @Dr.MV The $z$ in the numerator is $\sqrt z$ when you use substitution. How did it become just  $z$? I understand the remainder of the steps but I am confused about the initial step to have that as the numerator.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sure, but doesn't rationalizing the denominator and taking the limit seem so trivially simple and doesn't even require one to have studied derivatives.  And in determining the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ one is faced with ... rationalizing a numerator and taking a limit.  So, it seems a bit awkward in my very humble opinion.  -Mark

Comment: @goldenlinx $z=x^2+y^2$, not $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$...;-))... I see that I had a typo in the numerator of the original limit.  I've edited to correct.  Good catch.

Comment: @Dr.MV oh man I'm sorry about that one, studying for exams has taken a toll on me. Thank you for your help,  I really appreciate it!

Comment: @goldenlinx No need to apologize.  Best of luck on the ensuing tests!  And you're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Comment: Agree that it would lead to circular reasoning in the sense you described.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of limit problem, first fix $x$ to be 0, and check the limit is 2 when $y$ approaching 0. Then fix $y$ to be 0, and check the limit is 2 when $x$ approaching 0. So you can conclude the limit 2 is correct for this problem.

Above method comes from some old memory when I studied multivariable calculus. If the limit doesn't exist at all, the two trials above will give different values. For detailed example, see "Calculus" by Stewart 6th edition page 908.

Comment: That method is not sufficient - at all.

Comment: That would not be a correct approach- for a limit to exist for this type of situation, the function must approach the same value when the point is approached from $\textit{every}$ path, not just two.

Comment: @Harry Limits are not approached along paths.

Comment: How would it be properly worded?

Comment: For all $\epsilon$, there exists an open disk around $(0,0)$ such that whenever $(x,y)$ is in that disk $\left|\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}-1}-2\right|<\epsilon$.  The idea of examining a limit along a given set of contours is useful sometimes to show that a limit fails to exist.

Comment: I understand what the user intends to present here as the solution, although you are not given the answer. I only know the value is 2 because I look at the answer manual. Moreover, you cannot use the method indicated by going along the y and x axis to come to one point.

Comment: I was trying to give a visually why the commentor's method was very flawed. But you're absolutely correct Dr.